# Getting a field value from Redux form returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

What I'm having makes me bang my head in the code, comparing it with the guidelines from [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) and [Redux form](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/). I'm trying to get a field value, but I'm continually receiving *undefined*. 
What I have is:

```
const myForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
})(MyComponentClass);

const mapStateToProps = ((state) => ({
  l10n: l10nService,
  formValues: getFormValues('myForm')(state),
}));

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(myForm);
```

When I try to output formValues like

```
console.log(formValues);
```

I'm getting constantly undefined. This is frustrating as I'm re-reading the docs and can't find where the problem is. I'm visualizing the field with a method like this:

```
addSelectFieldD(element, key) {
  return (<Field
    key={key}
    name={element.name}
    label={l10nService.translate(element.label)}
    component={SelectField}
    units={element.units}
    options={this.props.selectOptions}
    onChangeDuration={this.onChangeDuration}
    onRetrieveSelectOptionsError={this.onRetrieveSelectOptionsError}
    informationMessage={l10nService.translate(element.tooltip)}
    submitted={this.state.formSubmitted}
  />);
}
```

Interesting thing is that I'm able to get formValues in some other component. I would highly appreciate any help guys as I'm so stacked with this.

EDIT: I've created an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-9fke1)

Comment: What's going on with your mapStateToProps function? Why is it wrapped in so many parentheses?

Comment: Can you share the file where you try to `console.log(formValues);` A Fiddle or codesandbox would be helpfull to understand the exact problem.

Comment: do

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        console.log(state)
        return {
            value: 'value'
        }
    }
What it gives you

Comment: console.log(this.props.formValues)  =>  undefined

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vladyn/39f5b6214698e978c2c50aab7bf23943#file-mapstatetoprops-js

Comment: it gives me: {
  "form": {
    "registeredFields": {
      "select1": {
        "name": "select-product",
        "type": "Field",
        "count": 1
      },
      "select2": {
        "name": "select-duration",
        "type": "Field",
        "count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so i have figured out the problem, in redux form if you dont provide some initial value to a form field it will be undefined rather than an empty object.

To give you an idea i have updated the sandbox with the initial value for the field
so now on this.props.formValues you will get the default value of the field, 
obviously onChange is not handle so it remains the same even if you change the value from dropdown, you can change that, but you get the idea,

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-butterfly-xon1n) you can look how its done, basically i have provided the initial value for form as

```
const myForm = reduxForm({
form: "myForm",
initialValues: {
 my: "value1",
 },
})(MyForm);
```

UPDATE: As you are using react-select as the select component so you need to dispatch a change action when you change dropdown value as

```
onChangeSelect = (props, newOption) => {
  this.props.dispatchChange(formName, fieldName, value)
}
```

I have updated sandbox for complete working example of your case
Hope it helps now

Comment: can you make a sandbox so its easy for me to check?

Comment: Ok - I'll try as they are lots of dependencies

Comment: @ibsam I've created an example here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-pond-9fke1

Comment: Interesting spot indeed, but I would ask - why the value after update of the select field is still the initial one of an empty string ("")?

Comment:  OK doing so you're initializing a form "values", which is popping out in the console as "formValues()", but the field we are talking about is still not connected with the redux form for some reason.

Comment: Indeed - this was the issue. Thank you @ibsam!

Comment: sorry for the delay, glad it helped you :-)

Comment: I would add to the answer this article I found, which explains the case  very clear - https://www.firehydrant.io/blog/using-react-select-with-redux-form/